# How can I use MongoDB to find documents that match with custom field?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am trying to find all documents that match with custom field in node.js.

node.js code:

```
req.app.db.models.Property.find({
  user: {
    id: req.params.id
  }
}).exec(function(err, user) {
  if (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
  console.log("id:" + req.params.id);
  console.log("user:" + user);
  res.status(200).json(user);
});
```

But, console shows like this

```
id:5941cfc42df14b2fe811d531
user:
```

And the schema is like below

```
user: {
      id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
      name: { type: String, default: '' },
      email: { type: String, defaul: ''}
    },
propertyType: { type: String, default: '' },
    ..........
    }
```

It seems that it can't find documents.
What's wrong with this?  Several documents exist on Property Collection.

Comment: `.find({ "user.id": req.params.id })`. Using `{ "user": { "id": req.params.id } }` is looking for documents with "nothing else" under the "user" key other than the "id" property. This of course is not true as it is at odds with the schema. See ["Dot Notation"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#embedded-documents) in the core documentation.

Comment: Hi Neil. I've just checked out with .find({ "user.id": req.params.id }) :)  and it's working now. Can you provide it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your query, its finding a user having an object id only.
So what you are actually equating is "user" with "{ id: req.params.id }" which return only id parameter. So for your solution do following:

```
var query = {'user.id':req.params.id}
Property.find(query).exec(function(err, user) {
  if (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
```

if you want to specify the type of object returned, if found. 
You can mention it as follows:

```
Property.find(query,'user.id user.name').exec(...)
```

this will return an object with user id and email only and not the name.